# How attach file from internal memory for background mail without Intent

Tags: android, email, background

I want txt file automatically attach from mobile memory to background mail.
Below code working properly for sending mail but no method for file attach that mail.

**GMail**

```
public class GMail {

    final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port
    final String smtpAuth = "true";
    final String starttls = "true";
    final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

    String fromEmail;
    String fromPassword;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    String toEmailList;
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public GMail() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
            String toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
        this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
        Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
    }

    public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));

            Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmailList);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(toEmailList));


        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
        // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
        Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
        return emailMessage;
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
       // Config.mailSuccess="1";
    }

//    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
//      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
//      DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
//      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
//      messageBodyPart.setFileName("download image");
//
//      //_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
//  }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;


        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }


        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }


}
```

**SendMailTask**

```
 public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

    private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
    private Activity sendMailActivity;
    GMail androidEmail;
    public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
        sendMailActivity = activity;
 protected void onPreExecute() {
        statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
        statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
        statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
        statusDialog.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
            publishProgress("Processing input....");
             androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(),  args[2].toString(), args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();
            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");



           // Config.mailSuccess="1";


        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());


    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        statusDialog.dismiss();

    }


}
```

**MainActivity**

```
String fromEmail = "sample@gmail.com";
                            String fromPassword = "xxxxxx";
                            String toEmails = to_sample@gmail.com;
                            String adminEmail = "admin@gmail.com";
                            String emailSubject = "App Registration Mail";
                            String adminSubject = "App Registration Mail";
                            String emailBody = "Your message";
                            String adminBody = "Your message";
                            new SendMailTask(YOurActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                                    fromPassword, toEmails, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

please anyone help me for attach file from mobile internal memory.

Comment: You commented out the file attachment code. Hence, that code will not run. What is your **actual problem**?

Comment: Commented attachment code not working.

Comment: There are [many Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com), offered in many languages. You may find that other sites will be easier for you to use. Otherwise, please explain, in detail, what "not working" means.

Comment: public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
      messageBodyPart.setFileName("download image");

      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  } that function not working. file not attached in mail.

Comment: I want  mail sent in background with file attach from mobile memory in background without intent or user interaction.