# Send a Mail with attachment in background Android

Tags: android, email

I want mail sent in background with file attach from mobile memory in background without intent or user interaction.

Please help me.

Comment: you search on google ? https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=R-3qVIWhMsWGvASI94DwDQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=android+send+email+programmatically+background

Comment: searched mail sent succesfully but no method find for attach file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139317

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331491/android-send-e-mail-with-attachment-automatically-in-the-background

Comment: I already  implement this method but nothing. In this method log show  mail sent successfully but mail not sent.

Comment: @NabeelHafeez - consider telling us which language you're intend to use...

Comment: @Wolfgang Vogl- I develop android App with java and xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [JavaMail API and Java Activation Framework (JAF)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) here is

[Android library](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/)

Comment: I searching for android.

Comment: Javamail-android library is exactly for android.
Here is a step by step tutorial: http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-java-mail-api-in-android/27800

Answer (score 0):

Download javamal api jar files, and do like this

```
recpient= reciept.getText().toString();
      subject= sub.getText().toString();
      textmessage= msg.getText().toString();

    Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

     session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication("Your Gmail-ID", "Your Gmail_password");
     }
     });
     pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...",true);
     RetreiveFeedTask task= new RetreiveFeedTask();
     task.execute();
  }    
   class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<string string="" void=""> {     
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          try {

             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("</string><string string="" void="">Your Gmail-ID"));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recpient));
             message.setSubject(subject);
             message.setContent(textmessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

             Transport.send(message);


          } 
          catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             }
          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

          }
          return null;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
       pdialog.dismiss();
       reciept.setText("");
       msg.setText("");
       sub.setText("");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
   }


 }
```